# JSF JavaScript problem - "jsf" is undefined

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, jsf

my webapplication works very fine with: Opera, FF, Chrome, Safari.
Now i tested it on IE and there are some weird errors.
I debugged my website with IE and it said:

```
<a id="navi:searchButton" href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'activateSearchDiv();return false;','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'navi\'),{\'navi:searchButton\':\'navi:searchButton\'},\'\')');return false">Search</a>
```

**>> "jsf" is not defined  ( in jsf.util.chain ).**

But I do load these scripts:

```
<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="chooseDevice.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="navigationScript.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />
...
```

I think the identified "jsf" is available in jsf.js. Why does IE return this error?

These are just simple commandbuttons/links created with JSF tags:

Did I miss anything? Why does it work on all browsers except IE?
Unfortunately I didnt find any hints on google.

Regards
Johnny

Comment: Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. Are the generated `<script>` elements there in `<head>`? If not, then you probably mistyped the request URI in browser address bar. It needs to match `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a DOM element with the id set to "jsf"? IE has a strange bug that happens when we try to use global variables which occurs to have the same name as a element's id.

if that's the case, you can predeclare the variable (put a "`var varName;`" in a script block in the top of the page) or just rename the element's id.

More on that in the link below:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Mar/22/Internet-Explorer-Global-Variable-Blow-ups

Answer (score 0):

Place the JSF js declaration in the top of the JS declarations also surround these with h:head tag so I suggest changing to:

```
<h:head>
   <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.js" target="head" />
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="chooseDevice.js" target="head" />
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="navigationScript.js" target="head" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
```

Comment: The `target="head"` should already do that. Plus, what you've there is invalid syntax. The head should not be nested in body.

Comment: You're right, I just edited to fix the syntax errors, thanks!